# Assign Jquery tokeninput for a dynamically created table row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-tokeninput

**Edited**

**Table Template**

```
<table id="Newdiagnosis" style="display:none">
<tr>
 <td><input class="diag" style="width:200px" type="text" name="provider_diagnosis_dtls[#].diagnosis_code" value /></td>
<td><input style="width:500px" type="text" name="provider_diagnosis_dtls[#].diagnosis_desc" value /></td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="provider_diagnosis_dtls[#].diagnosis_level)" readonly value />
<input type="hidden" name="diagnosis.Index" value="%" />
</td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

**Jquery for adding row dynamically**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#N").click(function () {
     var index = (new Date()).getTime();
     var clone = $('#Newdiagnosis').clone();
     clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"%"/g, '"' + index + '"'));
     $("#diagnosis").append(clone.html());
     });
 });
```

I need to attach Jquery tokeniput for each textbox created dynamically. Is it possible?

**I tried the below code in Jquery**

```
$("#N").click(function () {
    var index = (new Date()).getTime();
    var clone = $('#Newdiagnosis').clone();
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
    clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"%"/g, '"' + index + '"'));
    clone.find(".diag").tokenInput("@Url.Action("SearchDiagnosis", "Preapproval")", {
         theme: 'facebook',
         preventDuplicates: true,
         searchingText: 'Searching...',
         tokenLimit: 1
    });
    $("#diagnosis").append(clone.html());
});
```

This is not searching the data from the action given in url, but the same is working for non-dynamic textbox

Comment: You need to attach the plugins to the new elements. What is the purpose of adding the `id` attributes? And how would this post back (you have duplicate name elements)?

Comment: Hi Stephen,thanks for the reply. I won't have a duplicate name element because a unique id is assigning at the end of the element. Post back i need to look into it. Any other easy way which this can be achieved. I am new to MVC

Comment: You **DO** have duplicate name elements! There is no way this will post back correctly. The `id` attribute is irrelevant and you should be using `new { id = "" }` so you remove the id attribute to avoid invalid html. I suggest you look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) to understand how to dynamically generate collection items

Comment: attaching jquery inputtoken for dynamically created texboxes is possible?

Comment: Sure, just give the element a class name, then in the `$("#N").click(function ()` - `clone.find('.theClassName').tokenInput(....);`

Comment: Dear Stephen, I tried this in dynamic created rows but autosearch is not working, the same is working for non dynamic text boxed.

Comment: Also i had written a Onchange event for the class '.diag' it was working for static textbox but the same is failing for the dynamic one created through button. Any idea

Comment: For the `.change()` event, you need event delegation - so assuming you want to handle the change event of elements with `class="diag"` then `$("#diagnosis").on('change', '.diag', function() { // do something });`

Comment: Dear Stephen, thanks for the valuable comment. i will try and post the result but the jquery inputtoken is not working as the way i posted in the edited code. anything I am missing in that?

Comment: Sorry should have explained better - you need to add the element to the DOM first - `$("#diagnosis").append(clone.html());`, then `clone.find(".diag").tokenInput(...);`

Comment: Sorry if we are adding the token input after append the theme itself is not applying to the class but we are applying token input (like you mentioned first) as in the edited code the theme is getting applied but searching is not happening.

Comment: I take that back - since your appending `clone.html()` you would probably need something like `var html = clone.html(); $("#diagnosis").append(html); html.find(".diag").tokenInput(...);`

Comment: Dear Stephen, I am really sorry to disturb you this much time. assigning to var variable and find is also not working in my case :(

Comment: Hi Stephen the below code worked  var html = clone.html();
                    $("#diagnosis").append(html);
                    $("#diagnosis").find(".diag").tokenInput("@Url.Action("SearchDiagnosis","Preapproval")",
                    {
                        theme: 'facebook',
                        preventDuplicates: true,
                        searchingText: 'Searching...',
                        tokenLimit: 1
                    });

Comment: You probably want `$("#diagnosis").find(".diag").last().tokenInput(..)` so you don't keep reattaching the pluging to existing elements

Comment: Dear Stephen..you said it..what a fast reply..really helped me..thanks. a lot.. let me work on the OnChange event..

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly and add some code on the `.change()` event

Comment: Hi Stephen, .Change event working like a charm...with $("#diagnosis").on('change', '.diag', function() { // do something });

Comment: Next challenge for me is to post this to table..i may disturb you :)

Comment: This thread is getting too long. Time to ask a new question :)

Comment: :) Sure..will post new question and will tag you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the plugin to the element after the element has been added to the DOM

```
var diagnosis = $("#diagnosis"); // cache it
$("#N").click(function () {
  var index = (new Date()).getTime();
  var clone = $('#Newdiagnosis').clone();
  clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
  clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/"%"/g, '"' + index + '"'));
  diagnosis .append(clone.html());
  // Attach the plugin to the new element
  diagnosis.find('.diag').last().tokenInput('@Url.Action("SearchDiagnosis", "Preapproval")', {
    theme: 'facebook',
    preventDuplicates: true,
    searchingText: 'Searching...',
    tokenLimit: 1
  });
});
```

Side note: from your comments you indicated some elements have `onchange=".."`. You should remove remove behavior from your markup and use event delegation to handle dynamically added elements

```
$("#diagnosis").on('change', '.diag', function() {
  // do something
});
```